# Python npy file how to access variables

Tags: python, numpy, data-persistence

I have created a `npy`dataset by using the following tensorlayer command.

```
tl.files.save_any_to_npy(
save_dict={
    'images': aggregated_images, 
    'actions': aggregated_actions,
    'rewards': aggregated_rewards}, 
    name='./data/episode0.npy')
```

I am able to load the file (rewards/actions are arrays of scalars; images is an array of matrices) by using

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('./data/episode0.npy')
```

I thought this would be similar to a dictionary (`print(data)` works). Hence, I tried

```
actions = data['actions']
```

but this gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
>>> actions = data['rewards']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

> How can I resolve this error? I think I could use three variables to have a workaround, but I would rather like to only keep track of one file with all the.
>
> **Solution (credit goes to Goyo):**
>
> ```
> import tensorlayer as tl
> data = tl.files.load_npy_to_any(path='./data', name='episode0.npy')
> actions = data['actions']
> ```

Comment: It's a numpy array, probably object dtype.  Shape may be `()`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Any suggestion how I can access the variables actions, rewards and images?

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [docs](https://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/files.html#tensorlayer.files.save_any_to_npy)

Comment: @Goyo: *facepalm* didn't recognize that I could not properly load it with numpy. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
data = np.load('./data/episode0.npy').item()
data["actions"]
```

Comment: That's what `tl.files.load_npy_to_any` does - pull the single item (a dictionary) out of a 0d object dtype array.